# Adding ID to ag-grid row

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to identify the `div`s representing the rows of my `ag-grid`.

What I've tried:

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(rowNode => {
    rowNode.setId('opo-item-index-'+rowNode.data.lineIndex);
    rowNode.id = 'opo-item-index-'+rowNode.data.lineIndex;
  });
}
```

Neither of those has worked. Is there any other way to achieve this? The identifier doesn't have to be in `id` attribute, it could as well be in `data-*`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to redraw the rows after setting the id

```
this.gridApi.redrawRows({rowNode})
```